# Show years person has not been a part of

Tags: mysql

I have a table like this.

```
id Person year
 1 4  2001
 2 7  2001
 3 5  2001
 4 9  2001
 5 4  2001
 6 7  2002
 7 2  2002
 8 5  2002
 9 4  2002
10 6  2002
11 6  2003
12 4  2003
13 9  2003
14 2  2004
15 3  2004
16 7  2004
17 5  2004
18 7  2004
19 9  2005
20 8  2005
```

I would like for it to print all the years that person '9' has not been a part of.

I thought this was as simple as simply putting WHERE person!=9 GROUP by year, but that doesn't work, as if it ignores my where command.

It does however work the other way around when I say person=9 - then I only get the years that he has been a part of.

I have tried joining the table with itself. But no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select distinct yr.year 
from your_table as yr
left join
(
  select distinct year
  from your_table 
  where person=9
) as not_exist
on yr.year=not_exist.year
where not_exist.year is null;
```

OR

```
select distinct year from your_table 
where year not in (select distinct year from your_table where person=9);
```

Comment: Again, no luck on either. The last one still gives me all years.

Comment: impossible, make sure you check `select distinct year from your_table where person=9;` and `select distinct year from your_table`

Answer (score 4):

try:

```
... WHERE year NOT IN (SELECT year WHERE person = 9) ...
```

Comment: it shouldn't be too difficult `SELECT year WHERE year NOT IN (SELECT year WHERE person = 9) GROUP BY year;`

Comment: It doesn't work, it spits out number year 2001 despite person 9 being there.

Comment: @Michael person 9 is in 2002 year, I don't understand what do you mean by ignoring the where clause.